# Polyline calls an Image in setTag

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

My codes for polyline.

```
Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .clickable(true)
            .add(
                    new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                    new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                    new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                    new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                    new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                    new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309))
.width(10)
.color(Color.Red)
);
polyline1.setTag(" ");
```

Can I put/call Images in this `setTag`?

```
polyline1.setTag(" ");
```

Comment: why do you want to set any "image" as a tag? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add an image of "Road blocked (image)" , "Underconstruction (image). When the polyline is clicked the image will show above the polyline. Is it possible? or Any recommendation?

Comment: and do you think that calling `setTag` will do that? did you read the documentation?

Comment: I think no. I want to confirm it if it possible or not. Some of my professor said it can. No, what documentation?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline - *Tag
An Object associated with the polyline. For example, the Object can contain data about what the polyline represents. This is easier than storing a separate Map<Polyline, Object>. As another example, you can associate a String ID corresponding to the ID from a data set. Google Maps Android API neither reads nor writes this property.*

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my question!